# Getting rid of orphaned git commits

Tags: git

A git repo of mine seems to have some orphaned commits.

How can I remove them?

**What I've already done:**

`<hash>` is the hash of an orphaned commit.

`git log -n 1 <hash>` returns the info for the commit.

The following all output nothing:

```
git branch --contains <hash>
git branch -a --contains <hash>
git log <hash>..HEAD --ancestry-path --merges
```

I've already run the following commands:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

**Stash issues:**

The following:

```
git for-each-ref --contains <hash>
```

Returns:

```
<stash> commit refs/stash
```

Where `<stash>` is another commit hash.

How do I delete this from the stash?  I've tried the following commands, but nothing seems to work:

```
$ git stash show <stash>
# outputs some relevant info

$ git stash drop <stash>
error: '<stash>' is not a stash reference

$ git stash clear

$ git stash list

$ git stash show
No stash entries found.
```

Comment: Are you sure that commit is really orphaned? The `git gc` command you show here should ditch it.

Comment: What precisely do *you* mean by "orphaned"? Do you have added work-trees? What, if anything, does `git for-each-ref --contains <hash>` produce? Is `HEAD` attached to a branch name, or detached at some hash ID?

Comment: @torek: Thanks.  I ran that command.  The output is now in the bottom of my question.  I'll investigate using the stash, but if you know how to fix it, feel free to post an answer

Comment: "I guess I need to learn about the stash and how to remove commits from it." Start with `git help stash`. This is useful to add to your tool belt even beyond the context of this question..

Comment: I'm having problems with the stash.  I've appended more info to my question under **Stash issues** detailing my issues with the stash, if anyone can help.

Comment: `git prune` ? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune